# Not able to retrieve parameters from url in ADF

Tags: jsp, oracle-adf, url-parameters

I have only one page adf application, the page is called result.jspx. My requirement is - the url needs to be invoked with parameters like `http://example.com/ADF_View_Test-ViewController-context-root/faces/result.jspx?p1=1&p2=4` and my application should be able to extract both the `p1` and `p2` parameters and display result based on these parameters. I have implemented server & client listeners in the page which are able to run a method defined in managed bean when the page loads. So I need to extract all the parameters in my managed bean and process them to prepare result. How to do this?

In a try, I dragged and dropped the `result.jspx` page in my `adfc-config.xml` and defined page parameters in the property inspector like this - From value: `#{param.jobId}` to value `#{x.jobId}` where `x = pageFlowScope / SessionScope / ViewScope` etc. But nothing worked. I also tried using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("jobId")`, but it also didn't work.

I think the parameters that I pass are not stored anywhere. They just get lost. So can you please tell me solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/passing_parameters_to_an_adf_p which shows how to do this.

Timo